# MKV file corrupted

Tags: video-capture

I use the movavi screen recorder 10 program for screen recording. However, today, when I finished recording a video, the program stopped responding and I had to close it forcibly. Conclusion: the video has been corrupted. Is there any way to get it back?
OBS: I am completely stupid in informatics. If you can be patient, thank you.

Comment: Maybe there are parts of the file intact. But it's better to contact the publisher of your recording tool for support. Maybe they can tell you why this happened so you can avoid it in the future and they know best if there's a chance to recover part of the recording or not.

Answer (score 1):

2 things to try here

1. See if you can open it up in any video player you have on hand that can read the mkv file as mkv's do not require finalization to be played generally though they will only show the timestamps for the section that is currently playing.
2. Open it up in OBS and Use the Remux Recordings option to rerender your file and save it properly so all the finalization data is included